# The program skip clavier.nextLine

Tags: java, if-statement, iterator, java.util.scanner

While running the following code, and when I answer the question: Do you have more than 18years it directly say :

> -you are a adult
>   -create your password
>   -please create a password between 6 and 10 letters

Whereas It should have stopped at create your password. waited for my input, and if that input length is out of range, the next message should be shown.

But it doesn't waits for my input and displays the next message.

when I delete the question:
Do you have more than 18 years? (Yes/No)

the program work perfectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String password;
        String time;
        char adult;

        System.out.println("Hello,create your username:\t");
        name = clavier.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welkom " + name);
        System.out.println("Do you have more than 18 years? (Yes/No)");
        adult = clavier.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        if (adult == 'y' || adult == 'Y') {
            System.out.println("you are adult");
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("create your password:\t");
        password = clavier.nextLine();
        while ((password.length() < 6) || (password.length() > 10)) {
            System.out.println("please create a password between 6 and 10 letters");
            password = clavier.nextLine();
        }

        String password2;
        System.out.println("Please write your password again");
        password2 = clavier.nextLine();
        while (!password2.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("your passwords aren't the same");
            password2 = clavier.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("acount create");
    }
}
```

Comment: It somehow, works for me. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @MohitKanwar: there's no error message, but it **is** skipping a line. It automatically goes to the line that states that the password entered is not correct. Please check it and see. Also, why are folks down-voting a legitimate question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Ohh. I missed it because the message sequence looked logical. Showing number of characters required for a password just after requesting to create one. :D  
Understood the problem now.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   People are downvoting this question as the description is not very clear. I have tried to edit it, If it makes any better. Please approve.

Comment: @MohitKanwar: so approved.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
clavier.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
```

Does not handle the End-Of-Line (EOL) token, and so it is swallowed in your next call to `clavier.nextLine()`, messing you up. One solution is to call `clavier.nextLine()` immediately after the line above

```
adult= clavier.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
clavier.nextLine(); // to handle and dispose the EOL token
```

or simply use nextLine in the code above:

```
adult = clavier.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line

```
clavier.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
```

As per the documentation for this method

> If horizon is `0`, then the horizon is ignored and
>        * this method continues to search through the input looking for the
>        * specified pattern without bound. In this case it may buffer all of
>        * the input searching for the pattern.

Hence, instead of using that, you may use the following code.
I have basically converted `char adult` to  `String adult` and used `nextLine()` method as in other cases of yours.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class mmm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String password;
        String time;
        String adult;

        System.out.println("Hello,create your username:\t");
        name = clavier.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welkom " + name);

        System.out.println("Do you have more than 18 years? (Yes/No)");

        //adult = clavier.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        adult = clavier.nextLine();
        if (adult.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("you are adult");
        } else {
            System.exit(0);

        }

        System.out.println("create your password:\t");

        password = clavier.nextLine();

        while ((password.length() < 6) || (password.length() > 10)) {
            System.out
                    .println("please create a password between 6 and 10 letters");
            password = clavier.nextLine();
        }

        String password2;
        System.out.println("Please write your password again");
        password2 = clavier.nextLine();
        while (!password2.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("your passwords aren't the same");
            password2 = clavier.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("acount create");

    }
}
```